# Matching Regex C# in specific brackets

Tags: c#, regex

In a C# .NET5 application, I want to parse this string with a regex expression :

```
    (* <CatalytUx::Action
        Category="/Production/Station2/Commands"
        Enabled= ./IsEnabled        
        EndAction=Done
    /> *) 
    Parameter="None"
    (*
       <CatalytUx::Parameter 
        Category="/Configuration/Station2"
        Unit="ms"
        Decimals=2
    />  
    *)
```

The matches should look like :

- Match 1 : Category="/Production/Station2/Commands"
- Group 1 : Category
- Group 2 : /Production/Station2/Commands

I tried using this regular expression : `@"(\w+)\s*=\s*""?(.+)\b""?"` which is global and multi-line. Overall, it does the job but I don't want to capture `Parameter="None"`. I only want this pattern to be recognised while it is in the `(* *)` brackets.

Comment: If it wasn't C# you could use `\(\*\s*[^ ]+"?\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*""?(.+)\b""?"?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can make use of the [Group.Captures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-7.0) property to get repeating capture groups.

In this case group 1 has the value for the key, and named group `val` has the value.

Assuming all the key=value pairs are between the angle brackets:

The pattern matches:

```
\(\*\s*<(?:[^<>=]*\b(\w+)\s*=\s*(?:""(?<val>[^""]*)""|(?<val>\S+)))+[^<>]*/>\s*\*\)
```

- `\(\*` Match `(*`
- `\s*<` Match optional whitespace chars and `,`
- `(?:` non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `[^<>=]*` Match optional chars other than `<` or `>` or `=`
  - `\b(\w+)` A word boundary, then capture 1+ word chars in **group 1**
  - `\s*=\s*` Match `=` between optional whitespace chars
  - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

    - `""(?<val>[^""]*)""` Capture 1+ chars other than `"` between `"`
    - `|` Or
    - `(?<val>\S+)` Named group **val** matching 1+ non whitespace chars
  - `)`
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times to match at least 1 key value pair
- `[^<>]*` Match 0+ chars other than `<` or `>`
- `/>\s*` Match `/>` and optional whitespace chars
- `\*\)` Match  `*)`

See a [.NET Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qyPINZ/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/GBiTwv).